# Ant built does not generate class files

Tags: java, ant

I'm using build.xml to build my src. However it failed to generate class files without any error message. The full script is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<project name="auxiliary" basedir="." default="dist">

<property name="src.dir" value="../auxiliary-src/com/nextbio/drugbank"/>
<property name="dist.dir" value="dist"/>
<property name="lib.dir" value="../jboss_config/common_app_jars"/>
<property name="temp.dir" value="temp"/>
<property name="foo_dist.dir" value="../foo/dist"/>

<path id="libs-classpath">
    <fileset dir="${foo_dist.dir}">
            <include name="foo.jar"/>
    </fileset>  

</path> 
<target name="dist" depends="auxiliary-dist" />


<target name="auxiliary-cleanup">
        <delete dir="${temp.dir}"/>
        <delete dir="${dist.dir}"/>
        <echo message="cleaned up. ${temp.dir}, and ${dist.dir} have been deleted."/>
</target>

<target name ="auxiliary-dist">

    <delete dir="${temp.dir}"/>
    <echo message="delete ${temp.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${temp.dir}"/>

    <javac destdir="${temp.dir}" source="1.6" target="1.6" debug="on" fork="true" memorymaximumsize="1024m">
        <src path="${src.dir}"/>
        <classpath>
            <path refid="libs-classpath"/>          
        </classpath>
        <include name="com/car/**"/> <!-- troubled line -->

    </javac>
    <!--<copy overwrite="true" todir="${temp.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
            <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
            <exclude name="**/*.sql"/>
            <exclude name="**/*.txt"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy> 
     <delete dir="${dist.dir}"/>
     <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}"/>
     <jar destfile="${dist.dir}/auxiliary.jar" basedir="${temp.dir}"/> -->

</target>
```

There is no class file in ${temp.dir} after this step, and no error message. I double checked it, and found it is because of the "troubled line". I tried to add some files to the classpath. I don't know why it is wrong.

Comment: did you try defining the src path on the javac tag ?

Comment: Can you post the output of ant? Also, can you post the complete build.xml? That'll help to troubleshoot this. Cheers.

Comment: run it using ant -v to have more debug information. Maybe temp.dir or src.dir are not defined, or don't contain the value you think they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source path should point to the root of the package tree. You make it point to a specific package inside the sources : `../auxiliary-src/com/nextbio/drugbank`.

And in the javac task, you ask it to compile all the files matching the pattern `com/car/**`. That means that it will compile the Java source files in `../auxiliary-src/com/nextbio/drugbank/com/car` or in a subdirectory. If that's the case, you have very unconventional package names.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

My project complilated well but the classes there weren't in nowhere and It didn't have any error message.

My problem was the classpath. The eclipse wizard added  EclipseLink 2.5.1 jars.
I removed it and the problem is gone.

I suggest make a simple HelloWord and remove all jars 
reference from the classpath and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this "ant, javac, compile" problem related with the classpath to.

No debug or verbose message shown.

This behavior appear because in classpath exists not compatible (superior) version jar packages and that cause no output classes.